# How to refer to java fields or getters ? (variable column excel sheet)

Tags: java, excel, oop, design-patterns

This is more of a "Design" or "Conception" sort of question.

So I have a simple problem; I want to print some workers info in an Excel sheet.
But I want to do it in a way that is easy to change in the future, let me explain : for now, people just want to see last name, first name and address in that excel table. But, what if all of a sudden they want more ? Or less ? How to add or remove a column (that actually refers to a field in the Worker class) hassle free ?

In a simple picutre, I want a simple system to go from this (these would be excel sheets) :

```
| first name  |  age  |    job    |
-----------------------------------
|     joe     |   26  | developer |
|     mary    |   25  |  tester   |
```

to this :

```
|  first name  | last name  |   status  |    adress     |
---------------------------------------------------------
|     joe      |   johnson  |  employee | 8 sun street  |
|     mary     |   hoover   |    bos    | 6 moon street |
```

So my class is `Worker`, I thought about making a class that is called WorkerTabular that would have a `List` of `java.lang.reflect.Field` references in it, and then I can check, but I don't want to break the encapsulation, that would kind of defeat the purpose of making an "easily variable system", if all of a sudden we tie to the implementation and oversee getters. So instead I thought of storing the references to the getter methods in this List of columns. But how would I call that function reference I stored on an instance of `Worker`?

Something like (using the builder pattern) `WorkerTabular().addColumn(Worker::getName).addColumn(Worker::getHiringDate)` and then, in a third class like `ExcelMaker` do something like `worker.call(Worker::getName)` to get the name.

I want to keep things as segregated as possible to make a truly reusable thing, by leaving the `Worker` Entity untouched, encapsulating the tabular data we want in the `WorkerTabular`, and the actual work of making the Excel stuffs in the `ExcelMaker` class.

Am I missing a well known pattern to do all this ? After all, making a kind of "variable excel sheet" must not be a new problem.

In other languages like Javascript, I can kind of see how that would be done, WorkerTabular would be made with that builder pattern just that it's a List of Strings, and then in `ExcelMaker` we would just do `worker[listElement]` while iterating on the list of attributes we chose to be in the `Excel` sheet. But in Java, I can't really see a clean and "Javaic" way to do it.

I'm sorry if I'm asking a stupid question.

---

EDIT 1 :

Thanks to Justin Albano for his nice answer :).
You really nailed it I think with the usage of the interface, even the fact that not every field is a String can be handled in the Implementation of TableEntry, by doing the conversion there (Dates to Strings, Ints to Strings, etc). There is a bit of coupling between TableEntry and Worker, but it's kept there and TableBuilder can really just concentrate of it's job of iterating over the List of Strings and build the Excel file.

I'm having a bit of trouble figuring out how to add a "columns titles" line to the TableBuilder, but I guess I'll just do it like this :

```
class TableBuilder {
    List<String> columnTitles;
    String tableTitle;

    bytes[] build(List<TableEntry> lte) {

    // make first row, make title & iterate over entries

    // then do miscellaneous things like set the correct merged region for title, etc
    }
}
```

And initialize those fields with a static factory or builder.

Actually this problem arose :
there are two types of Workers, and they have two fields : email and work_email.

A type of worker has both, and the other type has only work_email. So with my implementation I'm screwed ! I would have to put BOTH fields in the Excel table,
and one would be empty for the other type of worker, and people would complain !

Or I would need to split the function generating the Excel file in two thus duplicating a lot of code, or handle this little weird case in the function making it really ugly.

With the implementation with Entry interface to represent data, I can get around this easy ! I get the feeling that it's a bit "overengineered" and certainly my colleagues won't like stumbling through this implementation I think (the codebase is more of a "straight to the point and ugly don't matter" kind of thing), but it's also very clean I feel.

Moreover, the class TableBuilder could build an excel file for any `Thing`, as long as an implementation class of `ThingEntry` has been made. That's pretty sweet !

Maybe the only real "issue" I see with it is that `2n` objects need to be created now, versus just the `n` of the 'ugly' implementation. But I feel that in 2018 that's not too big of an issue, right ?

Comment: Are you trying to do this in Excel (with VBA) or via Java?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple way to allow the internal representation of `Worker` to vary independently of the tabular representation of the `Worker` is to create a separate class for its representation. For example, given the following definition of `Worker`

```
public class Worker {

    private final String firstName;
    private final int age;
    private final String job;

    public Worker(String firstName, int age, String job) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.age = age;
        this.job = job;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public String getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public String getJob() {
        return job;
    }
}
```

the following wrapper can be created:

```
public interface TableEntry {
    public List<String> getColumnValues();
}

public class WorkerTableEntry implements TableEntry {

    private final Worker worker;

    public WorkerEntry(Worker worker) {
        this.worker = worker;
    }

    @Override
    public List<String> getColumnValues() {
        List<String> columns = new ArrayList<>();
        columns.add(worker.getFirstName());
        columns.add(String.valueOf(worker.getAge()));
        columns.add(worker.getJob());
        return columns;
    }
}
```

This would now allow another class, `TableBuilder` to depend only on the `TableEntry` interface, not the internals of `Worker`:

```
public class TableBuilder {

    public String buildTable(List<TableEntry> entries) {
        // Print header
        for (TableEntry entry: entries) {
            List<String> columns = entry.getColumnValues();
            // Print each column
        }
    }
}
```

Then the `TableBuilder` can be called as follows:

```
List<Worker> workers = ...

List<TableEntry> entries = new ArrayList<>();
for (Worker worker: workers) {
    entries.add(new WorkerTableEntry(worker));
}

TableBuilder builder = new TableBulder();
builder.buildTable(entries);
```

This ensures that if the fields or methods of `Worker` change, its representation in the table does not necessarily change; and vice-versa, if the representation in the table needs to change, that the `Worker` class does not necessarily need to change (the two are independent). If other tables need to be built, you can simply create more implementations of `TableEntry` and reuse the `TableBuilder` class.

If you wanted to store the getters of the `Worker` class as the means of building the table, you can do so, although doing so is a bit more complicated. At its most basic level, the getters are `Supplier<String>` objects, meaning that take no arguments but produce a single `String` value. For example, you can develop a `VariableTableEntry` in the following manner:

```
public class VariableTableEntry {

    private List<Supplier<String>> columnSuppliers;

    public void addColumn(Supplier<String> supplier) {
        columnSuppliers.add(supplier);
    }

    public String getRow() {

        for (Supplier<String> columnSupplier: columnSuppliers) {
            String columnValue = columnSupplier.get();
            // Print each column
        }
    }
}
```

The difficult part is that not every getter will return a `String`. Some, like `getAge()`, will return an `int`. To be able to print those getter references as a `String`, a conversion would have to be performed (this method would be present in the `VariableTableEntry` class):

```
public void addIntColumn(Supplier<Integer> supplier) {
    addColumn(() -> String.valueOf(supplier.get()));
}
```

This essential just wraps the supplied getter in a lambda expression that returns a `String` instead of an `Integer`/`int`. This process would be repeated for each of the other primitive values. Any `Object` (such as `Worker`) can be handled by deferring to `toString`:

```
public void addObjectColumn(Supplier<Object> supplier) {
    addColumn(() -> supplier.get().toString());
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer ! I edited my question to answer your post.

Comment: The issue with duplicate fields sounds like more of a design problem (deciding how the table should look) rather than an abstract problem. Are you looking to have a worker with both fields tabulated one way and a work with only one of the fields tabulated another way (i.e. have them put in two different tables or in the same table, but displayed a different way)?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean, there are no "duplicated fields" per se. no what I mean is that Worker has a status, and based on that status some fields are not filled, but still there. For the 'simple' worker type, the two email types are filled. For another type, only the "pro_email" is filled, not the "personal_email", so a whole column ends up empty in the Excel File. My solution is to just have two implementations of the table entry, one for the simple Worker and one for the Other, the other would return only the email field that it has filled in it's getColumnValues.

Comment: Okay, now I understand. That would be my solution as well. Having unused fields can be tricky, but your approach is a good one.

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood correctly, then Worker is your POJO and you are trying to create the list of POJOs and dumping in the excel sheet..So, what's the issue if person can add/remove the attributes in that bean class and corresponding getters/setters?